# How to add Custom data (like for Indoor floors) and find routes using open source software?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, indoor

I am a newbie to GIS platforms so maybe whatever I am asking is very simple or obvious. I have read documentation/tutorials and as a last resort I am posting here, so any help is appreciated. I am not asking for code per se just point me to the right direction.

I am trying to create an Indoor Map application, I have installed PostGIS and pgRouting on the server. Now, I am not sure what is the easy way to add nodes and ways to the database because in every tutorial/documentation that I came across, people are using OSM data. For me, there is no OSM data. Can somebody explain how can we insert node & ways to database so that pgRouting can work.

Thanks.

Comment: might be similar http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7158/are-there-any-indoor-gis-platforms

Comment: Sorry, but it's not. I am not using Google or any other company's product. I know such product exists, what I am asking is if I want to create such product how to go about it.

Comment: Okay..so you are creating using Open Source platform is that correct ??

Comment: yes. that's correct.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41877/from-pgrouting-shortest-path-back-to-osm-node-id

Answer (score 1):

You just create your own network topology. In this case you take your indoor plan, draw network on it and use it instead of OSM data.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do. But don't understand how to create nodes and ways in postgres. Any tutorials/documentation to which you can direct me to ? Thanks.

Comment: http://pgrouting.org/docs/howto/topology.html , assign_vertex_id(table_name, snapping_range, geometry_column_name, edge_id_column_name); it calculates topology using only start and end points

sp_assign_vertex